# Trying to Get Typography to Resemble a Particular Lettrine/Paragraph Display

Tags: pdftex, lettrine, drop-cap

I would like to imitate this display:

[image]

What I have so far is this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lettrine}
\usepackage{lmodern}


\input GoudyIn.fd
\newcommand*\initfamily{\usefont{U}{GoudyIn}{xl}{n}}


\begin{document}
\large

\lettrine[lines=3]{\initfamily{F}}{our} score and seven years ago our fathers brought forth on this continent, a new nation, conceived in Liberty, and dedicated to the proposition that all men are created equal.

\end{document}
```

Which produces:

[image]

Notice that in the paragraph I would like to imitate, the first line of the paragraph starts significantly below the top of the lettrine; whereas, in the second picture it begins barely below the top of the lettrine. Yet both paragraphs end at about the same spot relative to the lettrine.

QUESTION: How may I modify my code in PDFLATEX in order to more accurately produce the first display? (I don't care about the lettrine color, nor the bold ``our'' after it.)

Thank you.

Comment: With your code, I obtain a lettrine which is closer to the first image than the second.

Comment: @Bernard Do you think it is possible that different versions of Latex may produce slightly different displays of the same code?

Comment: LaTeX itself, I don't think so – unless perhaps if you have a very old versions. But a different version of the package might do so. I used  the latest version of `lettrine`, as far as I know: version 2.23 from march 2020. This being said, the package defines various parameters to fine-tune the result.

Comment: I get better results using `\lettrine[lines=3,loversize=0.2]`

Comment: @John Kormylo Thank you. The result is indeed much better.